# How can I display tooltips in widget options?

Tags: custom-options, widgets

It's easy to add comments and tooltips in system configuration options like this:

```
<parameters>
    <field_name>
        <comment>this is the comment</comment>
        <tooltip>this is the tooltip</tooltip>
    </field_name>
</parameters>
```

but these **do not work for widget options**.

I am able to display a comment in the widget options by using the `<description>` tag like:

`<description>this is the description</description>`

but, I have not found an easy way to add tooltips. Does such a thing exist?

**UPDATE:**

> I actually ended up simply using CSS to create the tooltips. Since widgets cannot use `<comment>` tags, I used `<description>` tags and CDATA to include the html with class like the following.

```
<description><![CDATA[Some informative text here. (<a module-title="This is the tooltip which will popup." class="module-tooltip">info</a>)]]></description>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.module-tooltip {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.module-tooltip:hover:after {
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(module-title);
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 220px;
}

.module-tooltip:hover:before {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 20px;
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not supported out of the box.
Take a look at the method `Mage_Widget_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Options::_addField()`. This is called (eventually) when building the widget options form.
The parameters for the field are build like this:

```
    $data = array(
        'name'      => $form->addSuffixToName($fieldName, 'parameters'),
        'label'     => $this->_translationHelper->__($parameter->getLabel()),
        'required'  => $parameter->getRequired(),
        'class'     => 'widget-option',
        'note'      => $this->_translationHelper->__($parameter->getDescription()),
    );
```

and later `$data['value']` is added.
You can try to extend this and add a new element in the array called `after_element_html` where you can basically put anything, and work some magic through css and js to make that "anything" behave as a tooltip.

Comment: For what it's worth, I ended up just using CSS for the tooltips :)